# How to press Page Down key in Selenium to scroll down a webpage through Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to scroll down my web page. What Java command should I use in Selenium?

Comment: Do you want to scroll down arbitrarily or scroll into a target web-element?

Comment: Please add more details, why you wants to scroll page ? For which reason ? Any thing can be target on web page by selenium web driver.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling down a web page is not a valid *usecase* which can be validated perhaps you want to scroll down to bring a *WebElement* within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) to interact with it. To achieve that you can use the `executeScript()` method as follows :

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code and try,

```
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        // Launch the application       
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/test/guru99home/");

        //This will scroll the web page till end.       
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the code below :

1) Using Action class****

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            //Creating an object 'action' 
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            //open SoftwareTestingMaterial.com
driver.get(Site URL);   // Give site URL as name of the web page
            //sleep for 3secs to load the page
Thread.sleep(3000);
            //SCROLL DOWN
action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(3000);
            //SCROLL UP
action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_UP).build().perform();
```